# Hibernate: Partial lazy initialization?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a many-to-many association defined like:

Parent.hbm.xml:

```
    <set name="children" table="child_parent_map" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
        <key column="parent_id" />
        <many-to-many class="Child">
            <column name="child_id" not-null="true" index="child_parent_by_child"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

Child.hbm.xml:

```
    <set name="parents" table="child_parent_map" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
        <key column="child_id" />
        <many-to-many column="parent_id" class="Parent"  lazy="false"/>
    </set>
```

I am *quite* sure I am initializing `Parent.children` by walking the collection. Something like:

```
for(Child child : parent.getChildren()) {
    Hibernate.initialize(child.getAnotherProperty());
}
```

Parent has six children. However, in one session parent appears to have only five, and in another (2 seconds later, nothing changed in DB or in another session) - all six. Actually, I discovered it after detaching these entities from session with a custom cloner.

I thought that lazy collections are either completely initialized (i.e. all elements are), or not. Is it possible that somehow only a part of the collection was initialized? Can it be an issue with caching?

**EDIT**: This session handles a fairly large data set (a few thousands of entities). Is it possible that this is because some already-loaded entities got evicted from the session?

Comment: Have you set some value to the property "default_batch_fetch_size" ?

Comment: Could you post the code for Parent and Child? I'd start with looking at hashCode() and equals().

Comment: Michal is right, you probably have something in hashCode() and/or equals() that causes your object to behave strangely.

Comment: I did have an ID-based equals and hashCode. When I removed it the issue disappeared. Thanks guys, feel free to post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking your **hashCode()** and **equals()** methods, incorrect implementation of these methods often cause this kind of behavior.